# How to change the palette colors of WinRT XAML Toolkit Chart controls?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, silverlight-toolkit, winrt-xaml-toolkit

How can I change the palette colors of the chart controls in WinRT XAML Toolkit charting controls ?

For example I want to change the colors of the slices of a pie chart.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you search for "Palette" in the source of the toolkit you will see how the default style of the Chart control has a `Palette` property which is a collection of `ResourceDictionary`. You can apply it in a similar fashion in your app either as a chart `Style` or directly as its property, e.g.

```
<charting:Chart
    x:Name="PieChartWithCustomPalette"
    Title="Pie Chart with Custom Palette"
    Margin="70,0">
    <charting:Chart.Palette>
        <charting:ResourceDictionaryCollection>
            <!-- Blue -->
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <SolidColorBrush
                    x:Key="Background"
                    Color="#4586d8" />
                <Style
                    x:Key="DataPointStyle"
                    TargetType="Control">
                    <Setter
                        Property="Background"
                        Value="{StaticResource Background}" />
                </Style>
                <Style
                    x:Key="DataShapeStyle"
                    TargetType="Shape">
                    <Setter
                        Property="Stroke"
                        Value="{StaticResource Background}" />
                    <Setter
                        Property="StrokeThickness"
                        Value="2" />
                    <Setter
                        Property="StrokeMiterLimit"
                        Value="1" />
                    <Setter
                        Property="Fill"
                        Value="{StaticResource Background}" />
                </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <!-- Red -->
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <SolidColorBrush
                    x:Key="Background"
                    Color="#dc443f" />
                <Style
                    x:Key="DataPointStyle"
                    TargetType="Control">
                    <Setter
                        Property="Background"
                        Value="{StaticResource Background}" />
                </Style>
                <Style
                    x:Key="DataShapeStyle"
                    TargetType="Shape">
                    <Setter
                        Property="Stroke"
                        Value="{StaticResource Background}" />
                    <Setter
                        Property="StrokeThickness"
                        Value="2" />
                    <Setter
                        Property="StrokeMiterLimit"
                        Value="1" />
                    <Setter
                        Property="Fill"
                        Value="{StaticResource Background}" />
                </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </charting:ResourceDictionaryCollection>
    </charting:Chart.Palette>
    <charting:Chart.Series>
        <Series:PieSeries
            Title="Population"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
            IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Name}"
            DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}"
            IsSelectionEnabled="True" />
    </charting:Chart.Series>
</charting:Chart>
```

I am adding this to the sample project for future reference.

[image]